# Do variables in a loop get garbage collected or do they stay in memory?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Does the variable in this bit of code get garbage collected after the loop finishes or do I have X amount of `sSteamId` variables floating in memory forever?

If it does, how can I do this more efficiently? I only need `sSteamId` long enough to convert an `int` to a `string` and then append it to a `byte`, then it's no longer needed

```
for _, id := range steamIds {
        sSteamId := strconv.Itoa(id)
        requestURI = append(requestURI, ","+sSteamId...)
}
```

Comment: Bet this is fine, and GC certainly cleans up eventually, but `requestURI = strconv.AppendInt(append(requestURI, ','), int64(id), 10)` is the temporary-less version you might be thinking of.

Comment: If you ever get "X amount of … variables floating in memory forever" (without holding a reference to them somewhere) then you've found a bug in the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They'll get GC'd as any references to them are lost with each iteration.